# Area of a triangle inside of other triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

$BK$ and $CM$ are angle bisectors of angles $B$ and $C$. Let $L$ be the intersection point. If $AB=39,BC=42$ and $CA=45,$ find the area of $\triangle CKL$.

a) $756$

b) $252$

c) $126$

d) $140$

[image]

We can find the area of triangle $ABC$ by Heron's formula: $$S=\sqrt{63\cdot 21\cdot 18\cdot 24}=756.$$ I am stuck here.

Comment: find kc by angle bisector theorem then find inradius r by r=areaABC/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two observations that can get you to the answer quickly -

i) As $L$ is the incenter of the triangle, altitude from $L$ to all sides of the triangle is the same and that is inradius of the triangle $( = r)$.

ii) $A = r \cdot s$ where $A$ is the area of the triangle, $r$ is the inradius of the triangle and $s$ is sub-perimeter.

You have already found that $s = 63$ and you used that to find $A = 756$.

So area of $\triangle CLK = \frac{1}{2}r \cdot CK = \displaystyle \frac{756}{2 \cdot 63} \times \frac{42 \cdot 45}{42+39} = 140$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I really appreciate your help! I am grateful for all the times that you have helped me. Can I ask you why $CK=\dfrac{42\cdot 45}{42+39}$? Is there a formula?

Comment: Yes that is the formula you can remember and directly apply. It comes straight from angle bisector theorem which indicates $\frac{AB}{BC} = \frac{AK}{CK}$. Add $1$ to both sides, then $\frac{AB + BC}{BC} = \frac{AK+CK}{CK}$ i.e $\frac{CK}{AC} = \frac{BC}{AB + BC}$

Comment: Thank you I got it!

Answer (score 2):

Use angle bisector theorem to find ratio between area of ABC ($S$) and area of CLK ($S_1$). To be specific:

1. BK is angle bisector of angles B, so $\frac{AK}{KC}=\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{13}{14}$
2. Because of $AK+KC=AC=45 \rightarrow KC=\frac{14}{27}.AC=\frac{70}{3}$
3. CL is angle bisector of angles C, so $\frac{LK}{LB}=\frac{CK}{BC}=\frac{5}{9}$
4. $\frac{S_1}{S}=\frac{KC}{AC}.\frac{KL}{BK}=\frac{14}{27}.\frac{5}{14}=\frac{5}{27}$

Therefore, $S_1=140$